# PHP multiple file uploads progress bar with apc_fetch?

Tags: php, file-upload, apc

Is it possible to use apc_fetch and APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS to create progress bars for multiple file uploads?  I was thinking of using APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS in an array or something but it doesn’t work.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: I was using APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS too, but after seeing this JS solution, worked perfect:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642017/php-multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-not-working-using-json-and-javascript